# exams2openolat: shufflesections and navigation do not work

Tags: r-exams

I run the following command from the `exams2openolat()` [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRE9SGA1F7U) for summative online exams using R/exams

```
exams2openolat(exm, n = 50, name = "R-exams-OpenOLAT",
  points = 1, maxattempts = 0, cutvalue = 2, solutionswitch = FALSE,
  duration = 60, shufflesections = TRUE, navigation = "linear",
  stitle = names(exm), ititle = "Question", adescription = "", sdescription = "")
```

and get the error

```
## Error in rmarkdown::pandoc_convert(input = infile, output = outfile, from = from, :
## unused Arguments (shufflesections = TRUE, navigation = "linear")
```

When I leave the two arguments out, it works fine. In the YouTube tutorial  the command also works with the two arguments.

Comment: Did the answer below solve the problem for you? If so, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the vote counter on the left of the answer. If not, please refine the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two arguments have been introduced in version 2.4-0 of the package which was still the development version when the question was asked.

This point along with a few other details are explained in a blog post that accompanies the YouTube tutorial: http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/openolat_exam/